# Como receber mensagens de um GPS que utiliza GPRS via PHP?

Tags: php, lado-do-servidor, socket

Eu tenho um dispositivo Gosafe G91i, um aparelho GPS que manda sua localizacao de tempos em tempos para um IP e uma porta que eu posso configurar. No momento, estão setados IP e porta de um servidor online (Orange gps-trace) e eu gostaria de setar para um servidor meu, aonde armazenarei os dados. Em um primeiro momento, não preciso de performance, só quero ver se consigo receber as mensagens. Que tipo de servidor PHP devo utilizar? Pode ser algum socket simples? Alguma sugestão? Obrigado.

Segue o código PHP que tenho até agora do servidor socket, ainda não tratando as mensagens.

Comment: 404 - Código de PHP não encontrado.

Comment: Edit: Por acaso não foi o código hehe. Achei a resposta, vou responder a minha própria pergunta em alguns instantes.

Answer (score 2):

Eu encontrei a resposta nessa pergunta do Stack Overflow: [How to listen to a TCP port using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054291/how-to-listen-to-a-tcp-port-using-php)

Configurei o GPS utilizando o comando (sem aspas):

```
*IP#senha_padrao#IP_Externo#Porta#
```

Coloquei o meu IP interno da rede no [código que o usuário Meraxes postou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13054630/1287812), a mesma porta e pronto, funcionou, estou recebendo as mensagens do GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui fazer o gps conectar com esse [codigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054291/how-to-listen-to-a-tcp-port-using-php) 
como trato e qual a variavel que capta as msgs?

```
require_once('/webserver/production/htdocs/assets/SocketServer.class.php'); // Include
    $server = new SocketServer("192.168.1.4",5008); //Criar um servidor de ligação para um determinado endereço IP e ouvir a porta 5008 para conexões
    $server->max_clients = 10; // Número de conexoes simultanea permitido
    $server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect"); // Executa a funcao handle_connect cada vez que alguem se conecta
    $server->hook("INPUT","handle_input"); // Executar handle_input sempre que é enviado um texto para o servidor
    $server->infinite_loop(); // Inicia o servidor

    function handle_connect(&$server,&$client,$input){
        $this->db->query("insert into teste (texto) values ($input)"); ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ","");
    }

    function handle_input(&$server,&$client,$input){// tratar entrada aq
        $trim = trim($input); // removendo espaços no texto de entrada

        //$this->db->query("insert into teste (texto) values ($trim)");///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if(strtolower($trim) == "quit"){ // Parar servidor
            SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"Ok! Goodbye..."); // Give the user a sad goodbye message, meany!
            $server->disconnect($client->server_clients_index); // Disconecta o cliente
            return;
        }

        $output = strrev($trim); // inverter string
        SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,$output); // envia o texto invertido
        SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ",""); // solicitar outro texto
    }
```